# MySQL ordering of messages based on the most recent message sent or received

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables `users`, `swipes` and `messages`. `users` contains the details of the registered users. `swipes` contains the list of connected users (friend request sent/accepted). `messages` contains the messages transacted between the connected users.

With these, I am building a web based threaded chat application like facebook or whatsapp. I am currently able to list all the connected users available for chat. However, I am unable to order them using the most recent messages sent or received. The user with whom the most recent message (sent/received) was transacted should be shown at the top of the list.

Sample table: `users`

```
id    name
1     John
2     Mary
3     David
```

Sample table: `swipes` (Here, you can see that John is connected with both Mary and David)

```
id    swp_from    swp_to    first_swp    second_swp
1     1           2         like         like
2     3           1         like         like
```

Sample table: `messages` (Here, `incoming_msg_id` is the sender's user id and `outgoing_msg_id` is the receiver's user id)

```
id    incoming_msg_id    outgoing_msg_id    msg
1     1                  2                  Hi, Mary 
2     1                  3                  Hey, David
```

Current query that generates the list of connected users I choose to chat with:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
(id IN (SELECT swp_from FROM swipes WHERE swp_to = :user AND (first_swp = 'like' OR first_swp = 'superlike') AND (second_swp = 'like' OR second_swp = 'superlike')) OR
 id IN (SELECT swp_to FROM swipes WHERE swp_from = :user AND (first_swp = 'like' OR first_swp = 'superlike') AND (second_swp = 'like' OR second_swp = 'superlike')))
```

Then I use the PHP while loop to display records from the above query. However, this does not order the list as expected. I want to order them based on messages in such a way the the user's thread with whom the most recent message was transacted is sent to the top. Say for example, David was at third position but then suddenly I opened his chat and sent him a new message (or I received a message from his side), with that his thread will be pushed to the top of the list (just like facebook messenger or whatsapp). I tried a lot but all my joins were a disaster. I am not being able to frame the query properly.

**UPDATE**

I tried the following query. This can give an idea of what I am trying to achieve. However, this isn't working.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
(id IN (SELECT swp_from FROM swipes WHERE swp_to = :user AND (first_swp = 'like' OR first_swp = 'superlike') AND (second_swp = 'like' OR second_swp = 'superlike')) OR
 id IN (SELECT swp_to FROM swipes WHERE swp_from = :user AND (first_swp = 'like' OR first_swp = 'superlike') AND (second_swp = 'like' OR second_swp = 'superlike')))
ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages WHERE incoming_msg_id = :user OR outgoing_msg_id = :user) DESC
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT swp_to uid FROM swipes WHERE swp_from = :user AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
UNION
SELECT swp_from uid FROM swipes WHERE swp_to = :user AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')) u
JOIN messages m ON u.uid IN (m.incoming_msg_id, m.outgoing_msg_id)
JOIN users usr ON u.uid = usr.id
GROUP BY u.uid ORDER BY MAX(m.id) DESC
```

Comment: If you want things in order of time then you need a timestamp column on your messages. Without that you can't guarantee that you'll get things in the right order.

Comment: Order in the `id` **desc**  if its autoincrement, the last `id` is the last message sent

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular as RiggsFolly stated, I was hoping to order it using `ORDER BY messages.id DESC`. That would do the trick without timestamp just fine. My problem is that I am not being able to frame that query for this task.

Comment: You're assuming that `autoincrement` hasn't been fiddled with, and no `id`s are created manually. If you can guarantee that then `id` will work. I'd prefer to rely on an explicit timestamp.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I guarantee that `id` will never be altered manually in the `messages` table.

Comment: Cant't see how messages are related to swipes. You can join  the list of users from your query and sort users by max message id . Is it what you want?

Comment: @Serg What a co-incidence. I just tried that. Please see the updated question. However, that ain't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT u.uid, max(m.id) lastmsg
FROM
  (
   -- rephrased your query to get distinct user ids of interest
  SELECT swp_to uid
  FROM swipes 
  WHERE swp_from = :user AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
  UNION
  SELECT swp_from uid
  FROM swipes 
  WHERE swp_to = :user AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
  ) u
JOIN messages m
ON u.uid in (m.incoming_msg_id, m.outgoing_msg_id)
GROUP BY u.uid
ORDER BY max(m.id) DESC
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e39daeed4170685b8ea51f871683240)

User info can be added with an extra join

```
with maxid as (
 SELECT u.uid, max(m.id) lastmsg
 FROM  (
   SELECT swp_to uid
   FROM swipes 
   WHERE swp_from = 1 AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
   UNION
   SELECT swp_from uid
   FROM swipes 
   WHERE swp_to = 1 AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
   ) u
 JOIN messages m
 ON u.uid in (m.incoming_msg_id, m.outgoing_msg_id)
 GROUP BY u.uid
)
SELECT u.*, lastmsg
FROM maxid
JOIN  users u on maxid.uid= u.id
ORDER BY lastmsg DESC
```

Comment: :  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
             ...' at line 2 in

Comment: Are you sure that query is for MySQL and not other SQL types like Postgree or something?

Comment: It's either = or IN but not both.  Take out =

Comment: 2 other differences from original: first_swp, second_swp logic should be OR not AND.  Also, last line Order By should be DESC not ASC.

Comment: But you removed `users` table from the query.. Now I cannot get the user details.. Can you please check?

Comment: User detailes  could be added with an one more join, see the second query

Comment: I used a simple join statement on your first query instead of what you suggested in your second query. I have updated that in the question as Update 2. Can you take a look and say how is that different from your suggested answer using `with`  because what I did works just fine.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer It will be AND not OR.

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap your last query looks ok to me.

Comment: @Serg there is something missing in my last query and also yours too. This only returns result for users whos messages existed. If message doesn't exist the users are not returned. In my first query there returned users with whom no message was ever transferred. In short, if the message table is empty then the list of users returned is Zero. Why is this happening? I mean if I never chatted with a user he should still appear in the list so that I can click on him and open the chat box and start chatting.

Comment: It's exactly how inner join is intended to work. Replace it with an outer join, in my query  `.. LEFT JOIN messages m ..`

Comment: @Serg You are a genius.. If I were CEO of a company, you would be my permanent Chief SQL engineer :) Talents like you must be appreciated. Thanks a lot whole heartedly.

Answer (score 1):

So first create a single unified set of swp_frm records and swp_to records with a Union.  Then embed that result in a summarization query to get a single row per user.

```
    Select userid, username From (
        Select u.id as userid, u.name as username
        From swipes s Inner Join users u on s.swp_frm=u.id
        Where s.swp_to = :user And (first_swp in ('like','superlike') Or second_swp in ('like','superlike'))
        Group By u.id, u.name
      UNION
        Select u.id as userid, u.name as username
        From swipes s Inner Join users u on s.swp_to=u.id
        Where s.swp_frm = :user And (first_swp in ('like','superlike') Or second_swp in ('like','superlike'))
        Group By u.id, u.name
    ) X Left Outer Join messages m On X.userid in (m.incoming_msg_id, m.outgoing_msg_id)
    Group By userid, username
    Order by max(m.id) desc
```

Comment: I want to sort the list based on the most recent message but you did not include messages table in this query.

Comment: Updated based on your clarification.  This over-retrieves message, swipe combinations but gets the right summarization.